# Calling Swift from C

Tags: c, xcode, swift, swift2

I have seen many articles explaining how to call **C functions from Swift**, but I would like to explore the converse (if possible), to call **Swift functions from C**.

I have seen examples illustrating Swift functions in objC, but these do not get me any closer to my goal. Is this task even supported?

Comment: Just a guess, but no. You would need to setup the whole runtime for Swift from C which is no fun at all and will not make sense either. Calling a low level from a high level language makes sense for performance (or low level I/O) reasons. But vice versa it's simply - well I have no appropriate words if you know what I mean.

Comment: yea, I would assume similarly. It would just be nice to extend existing projects written in C with new modules written in Swift if it were possible.

Comment: Huh. As said: vice versa I would not have a problem but this way? Make a Swift scaffold and re-use your old C-code, step-wise replacing it by Swift code.

Comment: As a way to start dipping into swift in a cautious approach, it is more attractive to start by writing just a sub-module in Swift under an existing C application, rather than rewrite top half of your C code base.

Comment: Hello there @sam I'm in a similar situation right now, have you found the correct way to do this? Some guideline would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only supported way to call Swift code from C code is to use Objective-C between the two.

That's not to say that it's entirely impossible, but someone would have to come up with a `NSInvocation`-like utility and wrappers for objects that don't have an exact C representation.